# Block "Mobile Data Turned Off" Notification

Tags: notifications, push-notifications, att, lg-g5

I keep getting this one notification from `Call Services` on an AT&T LG G5 that says "Mobile Data Turned Off." Indeed, mobile data is turned off when I switch from cellular data to a wi-fi connection, but I don't need this notification. How can I stop this notification from appearing?

My one thought would be to have an app that blocks notifications that contain that certain text, but I haven't been able to find an app that does this. Notifications from `Call Services` can't be blocked in Notifications settings.

Comment: If the device is rooted, then you can try Xposed module NotifyClean.

Comment: @Firelord Thanks, but not rooted! Any other ideas?

Comment: Is it a sticky/permanent notification or can you swipe it out when it occurs? In the latter case, you can setup [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) to detect the notification and automatically and immediately swipe/cancel it out for you.

Comment: @Firelord I can't swipe it away, sadly. It never happened on phones with Lollipop, only now on Marshmallow.