# How to remove the persistent 'Mobile data turned off' message on Android 7.0?

Tags: notifications, mobile-data, user-interface, data, notification-badges

When I turn cell data off on a Samsung Android 7.0 non-rooted phone, the `Phone` app always displays a notification that data is turned off.  This results in 2 issues:

1. The notification area gets cluttered with too many notifications.
2. The `Phone` **app icon notification badge** in the launcher always shows at least 1 notification.  This is an issue because it is supposed to indicate how many phone calls have been missed.  Sometimes the device has cell data turned off, and sometimes it has it turned on; thus, there is no consistency with the meaning of that important icon's notification badge.

The notification is persistent, and cannot simply be swiped away.

Is there a way to resolve these issues that are caused by the persistent unwanted 'Mobile data turned off' notification?

---

*Related question for an older version of Android (Android Marshmallow) with a different device manufacturer: [Block "Mobile Data Turned Off" Notification](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/159809/block-mobile-data-turned-off-notification)*